# In a tetrahedron ABCD, find the coordinates

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

$A'$, $B'$, $C'$, $D'$ are the centre off mass points in each triangle in a tetrahedron $ABCD$. What are the coordinates for the vectors $AB'$, $AC'$, $AD'$, $A'B'$ using $AB$, $AC$, $AD$.

So far:

$$k_1AB + k_2AC+k_3AD=AB'$$
I don't know how to continue